# How to access the navigation stack NativeScript

Tags: navigation, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to create a breadcrumbs for my Nativescript-Angular application. I read in the navigation documentation that With `<page-router-outlet>`  when you navigate forward, the current page and views are saved in the native navigation stack.

How can i access this navigation stack? This way i can navigate back to a certain page the user wants to go to and clean up all the pages forward of that component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always query through the [Frame](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_frame_.frame) and [BackStack](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_frame_.frame#backstack), even use them to close multiple pages at one go in case of NativeScript Core.

For NativeScript Angular, there is a open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1367), but you could still use Frame / [NSLocationStrategy](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.ts#L64) to find all pages in history.